# More detailed Exception class for ClientWebSocket?

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm getting connection/transmission errors using the `ClientWebSocket` class.  Catching `Exception` isn't giving me much useful information.  Is there a better `Exception` class to use for this object?  I tried `WebSocketException` but the errors didn't seem to be of that type.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? doing debug you can understand which  type of Exception is thrown

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to get root cause of issue(s).